# How can I see background process in Ubuntu? And kill unnecessary processes?

Tags: kill, task-management, killall

In Windows by using `Task Manager` we can see how many `.exe` files are running. Also in `command prompt` we use `tasklist` command to see processes. In ubuntu how can I see all processes and kill unwanted processes?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the terminal, `ps -ef` will list all the processes. See `man ps`. See `man kill`, `man 2 kill`, `man  killall`, `man nice`, `man pkill`, `man renice`, `man 7 signal`, and `man skill` to mess with processes. However, simply killing a process that you think is useless may be a mistake. The system might restart the process, or something you depend on might depend on the process you killed. Learn what the processes do, and look at `/etc/init/` and `/etc/init.d`, `/etc/rc?.d`, `man service` to see how processes are started by the system.

Comment: You didnt answer how to kill. `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 25):

Using GUI, you can use System Monitor

[image]

Or from terminal you can use

```
ps aux | less
```

To view every process:

```
ps -A or ps -e
```

All processes running by a user:

```
ps -u username
```

To kill a process, either find the process name and type:

```
kill -9 processname
```

or kill the process ID (PID):

```
kill pid
```

Stop/suspend a process:

```
ctrl-z
```

Source:<sup>[Man Page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps)</sup>

Comment: can you plz explain how to via terminal with details?

Comment: I just added more info in my answer.  Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 8):

There is also the tool "htop". It is like "top", but has lots of other capabilities.

In a terminal enter:

```
sudo apt install htop
```

Answer (score 5):

My main tool here is `top`

type `top` at the command line in a terminal window

You'll get a list of the process that are running, listed by cpu usage.  Wait a few seconds for it to gather more stats before proceeding.

[image]

This is my main tool in unix for killing runaway or unwanted processes.  They are likely to be near the top of the list.  Note their pid and press `q` and then either 15 (soft kill) or 9 (hard kill).

Here you see me killing a Chrome process:

[image]

[image]

The process should go away.  Then type `q` to quit out of top.

If you find you are always killing the same processes you can also use `kill` or `killall` at the command line, for instance if `top` has shown several java programs taking up cpu you can `q`uit out of top and do `killall java`
`kill` and `killall` use 15 (SIGTERM) by default but you can override this with `killall -9 [process]` or `killall -s SIGKILL [process]`

Answer (score 1):

Another good tool to use will be [Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances).

[image: Glances screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this to perform the task in question, i. e. kill unwanted processes. It's not entirely obvious to me. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)